# LDAP- Error opening connection : xx.xx.xx.xx:389

Tags: ldap, openldap

I'm trying to connect the LDAP server available on cloud. The web interface for the server is  :  **xx.xx.xx.xx/phpldapadmin** where I can login and do whatever operation I want to do.

But when I'm trying to bind the ldap from my local machine through JXplorer, I'm getting connection timeout error. Here are the screenshots :

1. Connection Wizard

[image]

2. Error wizard:

[image]

3. Stack Trace

   `javax.naming.CommunicationException: XX.XX.XX.XX:389 [Root exception is java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out: connect]
   at com.sun.jndi.ldap.Connection.<init>(Connection.java:223)
   at com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapClient.<init>(LdapClient.java:136)
   at com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapClient.getInstance(LdapClient.java:1600)
   at com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtx.connect(LdapCtx.java:2698)
   at com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtx.<init>(LdapCtx.java:316)
   at com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtxFactory.getUsingURL(LdapCtxFactory.java:193)
   at com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtxFactory.getUsingURLs(LdapCtxFactory.java:211)
   at com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtxFactory.getLdapCtxInstance(LdapCtxFactory.java:154)
   at com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtxFactory.getInitialContext(LdapCtxFactory.java:84)
   at javax.naming.spi.NamingManager.getInitialContext(NamingManager.java:684)
   at javax.naming.InitialContext.getDefaultInitCtx(InitialContext.java:307)
   at javax.naming.InitialContext.init(InitialContext.java:242)
   at javax.naming.ldap.InitialLdapContext.<init>(InitialLdapContext.java:153)
   at com.ca.commons.jndi.JNDIOps.openContext(JNDIOps.java:529)
   at com.ca.commons.jndi.JNDIOps.<init>(JNDIOps.java:123)
   at com.ca.commons.jndi.BasicOps.<init>(BasicOps.java:55)
   at com.ca.commons.jndi.AdvancedOps.<init>(AdvancedOps.java:59)
   at com.ca.commons.naming.DXOps.<init>(DXOps.java:41)
   at com.ca.directory.jxplorer.broker.CBGraphicsOps.<init>(CBGraphicsOps.java:46)
   at com.ca.directory.jxplorer.broker.JNDIDataBroker.openConnection(JNDIDataBroker.java:477)
   at com.ca.directory.jxplorer.broker.JNDIDataBroker.openConnection(JNDIDataBroker.java:422)
   at com.ca.directory.jxplorer.broker.JNDIDataBroker.processRequest(JNDIDataBroker.java:396)
   at com.ca.directory.jxplorer.broker.DataBroker.processQueue(DataBroker.java:200)
   at com.ca.directory.jxplorer.broker.JNDIDataBroker.processQueue(JNDIDataBroker.java:913)
   at com.ca.directory.jxplorer.broker.DataBroker.run(DataBroker.java:165)
   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
   Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out: connect
   at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.connect0(Native Method)
   at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(DualStackPlainSocketImpl.java:69)
   at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:337)
   at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:198)
   at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:180)
   at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:157)
   at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:391)
   at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:579)
   at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:528)
   at java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:425)
   at java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:208)
   at com.sun.jndi.ldap.Connection.createSocket(Connection.java:365)
   at com.sun.jndi.ldap.Connection.<init>(Connection.java:200)
   ... 25 more`

Please help !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Connection timed out indicates that the port 389 is not accessible from your network. Make sure the firewall in cloud allows your ip to access port 389 of the LDAP host. phpldapadmin will work since it will listen on port 80/443 and it in turn connects with LDAP locally.

You can test the connectivity by running `telnet <LDAP Host> 389`. If the port is accessible from you host, you'll be able to establish a connection.

Comment: Tried telnet, but getting error as : Connecting To xx.xx.xx.xx:389...Could not open connection to the host, on port 23: Connect failed